# Corrupt Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM file on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, file-corruption

Good Evening,

I have a problem booting into Windows 7, and get an error when booting up:   error 0xc0000225 corrupt windows/system32/config/SYSTEM registry file

My question to you is that what is the healthy or normal file size of the SYSTEM registry file ?

I believe I got a virus and all my config files like SYSTEM, SOFTWARE, DEFAULT, SECURITY, etc. are exactly the same size and around 200-400 kilobytes (I cannot remember exactly the size).

I made a boot recovery disc, and in the boot cd it had a SYSTEM file that was over 2 MB.  Which is why I became suspicious that it was a virus.

Comment: I just want to make a comment is that I have no Windows 7 installation disc, and I was wondering how I can get a clean version of those system32 config files.

Comment: A clean copy of the file in question wouldn’t help.  The size of your System registry hive is entirely dependent on your system configuration.  You need a Windows 7 ISO at this point Windows must be reinstalled

Comment: Try F8 at boot, see if there is a "Last known good config that worked" option, select that and see if it boots now.

Comment: I read some help documents online, and they said that there was a backup in /Windows/System32/config/RegBack...but when I looked in that directory, the backup hives were exactly the same date and size as the ones under config...I copied them over and it still wouldn't boot.

Comment: Where would I be able to get a windows 7 iso, because the computer I bought never came with windows 7 cd's..